# Problem Getting the Reducto Spell in Year 6, Level 3

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

My daughters exited the room where they were supposed to acquire the Reducto spell and continued the game without it.  They can progress further into the game before getting it, but when they return to the class where they were supposed to learn the spell, it won't offer them the chance.  We restarted the level without saving, and the game still won't let them get the spell.  Is there a way they can back track and unlock the Reducto spell?

Comment: I presume you mean that they _can't_ move forward, otherwise your question would be pretty pointless.

Comment: Wait.. how did you exit the class room without the spell? The game doesn't allow you to exit the class until you have the spell - just like every other class in the game. You might have hit a glitch somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you already have it?

Comment: The Lego Harry Potter games are notorious for game-breaking glitches (I can name at least 5 I found in years 1-4), so a glitch could very well be likely. Are you sure that they are going to the right room?

Answer (score -1):

Yep it's a glitch. I encountered it too... Destroyed all the "metal" statues and nothing happened like REDUCTO SPELL LEARNED! instead was nothing. And I was wandering a bit around the class and then tried to walk away and guess what... I made it but without the spell. Now I'm stuck in the next level. Where reducto is crucial... Somewhere I read that to "fix" this is to start a new game and when you have lesson with Flitwick ONLY do things to acquire spell! Don't collect anything like character studs or gold blocks. Or this will happen again...